# How to get column with identity specifcation on for view created in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a view where one of my column is primary key.In that field identity specifcation is also set to yes.when i open the view it doesnot contains primary key field.When i set the identity specification to No then only my view contains the primary key field.What is the reason?

Are there any sql queries to set is identity to No?
[image]

My view :

> `create view userAccounts as select user_id ,br_id,user_name,role_id,
>   ,email ,created_dt ,updated_dt ,status from user_accounts`

Here user_id doesnot appear in my view.
[image]

Comment: Are you using the words View and Table interchangeably? A View is simply a virtual table defined by a query. You don't define your primary key on a view. On a **table** an identity, on it's own, isn't a primary key. The `IDENTITY` property and `PRIMARY KEY` constraint are 2 different things, and although are normally applied to the same column don't have to be.

Comment: Include the DDL of your View. A view's definition won't change based on if the `IDENTITY` property of a column is set to yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate the behaviour the OP is describing. In the SQL below, both queries against `v1` and `v2` return both the columns `ID` and `c`. If the column is no longer appearing in the view, then this means the definition of the view is being changed.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (ID int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, c char(1));
CREATE TABLE t2 (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, c char(1));
GO
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT *
FROM t1; 
GO
CREATE VIEW v2 AS
SELECT *
FROM t2; 
GO
INSERT INTO t1 (ID,c)
VALUES (1,'a');
SELECT *
FROM v1;
INSERT INTO t2 (c)
VALUES ('a');
SELECT *
FROM v2;
GO
DROP VIEW v1;
DROP VIEW v2;
DROP TABLE t1;
DROP TABLE t2;
```

Note that you cannot alter an existing column to become an `IDENTITY` column (or remove it). If you are changing the property within SSMS it is actually creating a new table, copying the data, dropping the old table, and then renaming the new one.